# Recessed lighting 10 x 10 Bedroom

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have a lake home that has a very small bedroom we are remodeling. Because of the room size the bed actually is located in one corner of the room. Currently have purchased four 4 inch recessed lights. As you might guess there is a recessed light right over the top of the bed close to the Head. Wondering if I should just use three lights in each of the other corners or would I be smart to try to use a wall washer or eyeball in the can over the bed? We do have a table lamp next to the bed so it's not like we would be without reading light. Other three cans I roughly 30in off each corner

Comment: why use overhead lighting at all?  ..... indirect lighting is much more pleasant in a bedroom

Comment: @jsotola 100% disagree.

Comment: @Sickest, interesting .... i did not think that anyone would like an overhead glare in a bedroom .... i am soooo wrong .... lol

Answer (score 1):

Put a dimmer on the room and put a lower wattage over the bed if it is bothering you.   Trying out a few bulbs with a dimmer you should be able to find something that dims pretty low compared to the others.   I would not be moving electrical and lights based on current room configuration unless you are going to be there a long long time.

Comment: Agreed, it makes zero sense not to install a dimmer switch + dimmable LEDS with recessed lighting, that way you can control how much light you want in the room. I would use all 4 units, not 3. And if you want to go the extra mile, get bulbs that can be control from your phone.